# heap memory release policy in Arduino

Tags: arduino

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "include/MainComponent.h"

/*
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.
*/


MainComponent* mainComponent;

void setup()
{

    mainComponent = new MainComponent();
    mainComponent->beginComponent();

}

void loop()
{

    mainComponent->runComponent();
}
```

is there any callback to release memory in Arduino ?(e.g to call delete mainComponent)

or this will happen automatically as the loop ends?

what is the strategy to ensure freeing the memory allocated in that code snippet?

**SCENARIO :"I wanted to access the object in both methods , so the  object is declared in the global scope then instantiated at setup."**

What happen when loop() terminated ? will  mainComponent still remain in the memory?

If it was in OS NO , process will terminated then resources will be deallocated.

So in Arduino how can I achieve above SCENARIO , by ensuring memory will be deallocated when the controller is switched off ?

Comment: On the AVR, you've got no OS, only raw hardware. Re-set the chip (cut power, press "RESET", etc.) and all the memory will be "freed".

Comment: So no need for careful memory mgt in Arduino like in OS based?

Comment: There's even more need for even more careful memory management, but that basically includes not allocating too much of the 2kB (or so) RAM. You If you need an object to be alive throughout the lifetime of your program, then you don't need to free it.

Comment: @H2CO3 it make sense. do you have any resource that could get better understanding about memory handling in Micro-controllers?

Comment: Well... I don't know. Honestly. You have to be careful. Apply the general memory management rules and remember that you only have 2k of them. Read compiler-generated assembler and/or the source code of `malloc()` in avr-libc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is confusing you is that the main() function is hidden by the basic Arduino IDE.  Your programs have a main() function just like on any other platform, and have a lifecycle same as when run on a computer with OS.  If you look under arduino___\hardware\cores\aduino, you will find a file main.cpp, which is included into your binaries:

```
int main(void)
{
   init();

   //...       
   setup();

   for (;;) {
      loop();
      if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Considering this file you will now see, that while you exit the loop(), it is continuously called.  Your program **never** exits.  In general, your best pattern is to new objects once and never delete, like you have done here.  If you are new'ing and delete'ing objects repeatedly on a microcontroller, you are not thinking about lifecycles and resources wisely.

So
"is the new'd object deleted at return from loop()?"  No, the program is still running and it stays on the heap.

"What happens at power off? Is there a way to clean up?"  The moment the supply voltage drops too low, the microcontroller will stop executing instructions.  Power supervisor circuitry prevents the controller from doing anything erratic as the voltage drops (should prevent)  When the voltage is conpletely drained, all the RAM is lost.  Without adding circuitry, you have no way to execute any clean up at power off.

"Do I need to clean up?"  No, at power up, everything is reset to a known state.  Operation cannot be affected by anything left behind in RAM (presumes you initialize all your variables).

Comment: many thanks for this detailed reply. really helpful! So the pattern I have used is correct in your opinion?

Comment: Correct in the sense it will work as you expect, and be reliable.  If you look at most of the Arduino code you would see that the objects would not be allocated with new, but instead have static initializers.  A key benefit is that you will know at link time how much memory is used.  With the new/heap your program uses, you won't know until runtime if you have enough memory.

Comment: I've been searching for some way to run a clean up function to free allocated data on program exit/close, but what you're saying makes a lot of sense. Thanks!